# Are there alternatives to querySelectorAll in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to refactor some javascript codes using React. What I'm trying to do is -> I have some elements which have the same className and I want to have control over each element. For this, in javascript I could just use the queryselectorAll and forEach functions, like

```
<Svg>
   <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="20" class="human"></circle>
   <line x1="100" y1="80" x2="100" y2="120" class="human"></line>
   <line x1="70" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" class="human"></line>
   <line x1="130" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" class="human"></line>
   <line x1="70" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" class="human"></line>
   <line x1="130" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" class="human"></line>
</Svg>

const wrongLetters = [];
window.addEventListener('keydown", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
    wrongLetters.push(e.key)
  }
}

const humans = documentSelectorAll(".human")
humans.forEach((human, index) => {
if (index < wrongLetters.length) {
    human.style.display = "block";
  }
  if (6 === wrongLetters.length) {
    popUpContainer.style.display = "flex";
    comment.innerText = "You have lost";
  }
}); }
```

However, I assume it'd be different in React even if I change 'class' to 'className'? For this, I've already searched some relevant posts and tried to use 'ref' but still don't know exactly what to do in this case.
Any advice would be appreciated.

+edit/ What I'm trying to do is every time I add an element to 'wrongLetters' array, each element in Svg tag will be displayed. Each Svg element is set to 'display: none' as default in javascript

Comment: Normally you do not interact with the DOM in react. Hard to give a god answer since we do not know what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: It really depends on the content of `do what I want here in Javascript`, can you elaborate a bit on what you'd want to do there?

Comment: In react you'd have a component that renders those elements, updating them or rendering different elements according to changes in application or component state. You _very, very_ rarely need to access the DOM directly in react.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks I edited my post

Comment: @rayhatfield Thanks. then should I wrap every svg element in components?

Comment: @Junyoung See my answer and working demo for what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `wrongLetters` into state that gets changed instead of pushing to the array. Then, in React, analyze that state to determine how many elements need to be hidden. Since this can encompass all of the functionality you're looking for, there's no need to be able to access the individual DOM elements with `useRef` or `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (!pressed.includes(e.keyCode) && e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
                setPressed(pressed => [...pressed, e.keyCode]);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <svg>
            <circle style={{display: pressed.length > 5 ? 'block' : 'none'}} cx="100" cy="60" r="20" stroke="black"></circle>
            <line style={{display: pressed.length > 4 ? 'block' : 'none'}} x1="100" y1="80" x2="100" y2="120" stroke="black"></line>
            <line style={{display: pressed.length > 3 ? 'block' : 'none'}} x1="70" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" stroke="black"></line>
            <line style={{display: pressed.length > 2 ? 'block' : 'none'}} x1="130" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" stroke="black"></line>
            <line style={{display: pressed.length > 1 ? 'block' : 'none'}} x1="70" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" stroke="black"></line>
            <line style={{display: pressed.length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none'}} x1="130" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" stroke="black"></line>
        </svg>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
line {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

That's the React way of doing things - use state when you can; avoid accessing/changing the DOM directly, just make the render reflect the state, and change the state when needed.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, in react you'd have a component that renders those elements, updating them or rendering different elements according to changes in application or component state. You *very, very* rarely need to access the DOM directly in react.

Here's a rough implementation of the sort of thing I mean. There's a [live/working copy of it on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pascal-4byqu?file=/src/App.js:0-1162):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

// an array of the svg elements; the component below renders
// a subset of these according to number of attempts.
// i'm not sure this is how i'd do this in the real world
// but it's good enough for this demo.
const segments = [
  <circle cx="100" cy="60" r="20" class="human"></circle>,
  <line x1="100" y1="80" x2="100" y2="120" class="human"></line>,
  <line x1="70" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" class="human"></line>,
  <line x1="130" x2="100" y1="75" y2="95" class="human"></line>,
  <line x1="70" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" class="human"></line>,
  <line x1="130" x2="100" y1="140" y2="120" class="human"></line>
];

export default function App() {
  // track the number of attempts in component state
  const [attempts, setAttempts] = React.useState(0);

  // handler for keydown events that for this demo
  // doesn't do anything besides increment the number of attempts
  const onKeyDown = React.useCallback(() => setAttempts(attempts + 1), [
    attempts
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // when the component mounts, add the keydown listener
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

    // when the component unmounts remove the listener
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  }, [onKeyDown]);

  // get the visible subset of segments based on number of attempts
  const visibleSegments = segments.slice(0, attempts);

  // return the new markup
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style={{ width: "300px" }}>
        {visibleSegments}
      </svg>
      {attempts >= segments.length && (
        <div>
          <div>You Lose or whatever</div>
          <button onClick={() => setAttempts(0)}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Brother if you want to access the DOM in React JS tou have to create ref using createRef() Hooks and then you can able to access the Dom in react like javascript

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

you can acess the node by calling this.myRef.current method

```js
const node = this.myRef.current;
```

You can  add the same ref in multiple html element and when u called this.myRef.current then all the element you put the ref you can access...